# CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors, laravel-passport

So I tried to just play a bit with front and back end.When trying to send data to server from front end I am getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://test.localhost/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Below is my axios setup for onClick:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
  return axiosClient.post('/login', { email, password })
    .then(response => {
      // handle successful login
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle failed login
      throw error;
    });
};
```

my axiosClient is:

```
import axios from "axios";
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, (my localhost)
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
export default axiosClient;
```

my cors config in backend is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://localhost:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization',
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json([], 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried including your localhost IP in cors.php like this?

```
'allowed_origins' => ["http://localhost:3000"]
```

If this is not working, Try with this config

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => ["*"],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => ["*"],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

and comment this line in Kernel.php but be careful this configuration will accept requests from everywhere so before deploying ensure that your backend receives requests from your preferred allowed origin.

```
 \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but it still doesn't improve.
But I get `Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "App\Policies\ModelPolicy" does not exist` in my `logs`. Is that the cause?

Comment: Check to see if the class exists in your file structure, If it exists and you are still getting an exception run composer du.